Can't instantiate Supabase client; fails with GoTrue error "window is not defined."
I've written a Deno-based server and am trying to use Supabase with it. However, on launch it fails with an assertion thrown from GoTrueClient.js, _isImplicitGrantFlow():
Exception has occurred: ReferenceError: window is not defined
  at SupabaseAuthClient._isImplicitGrantFlow (file:///Users/me/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/@supabase/auth-js/2.64.2/dist/main/GoTrueClient.js:1138:62)
    at SupabaseAuthClient._initialize (file:///Users/me/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/@supabase/auth-js/2.64.2/dist/main/GoTrueClient.js:170:64)
    at file:///Users/me/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/@supabase/auth-js/2.64.2/dist/main/GoTrueClient.js:155:35
...
    at new SupabaseAuthClient (https://jsr.io/@supabase/supabase-js/2.44.3/src/lib/SupabaseAuthClient.ts:6:5)

I try to create the client as follows:
import { createClient } from 'jsr:@supabase/supabase-js@2';
import { Database, Tables, Enums, TablesInsert, TablesUpdate } from './DBTypes.ts';

export const supabase = createClient<Database>('http://localhost:54321', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiblahblahblahXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZS1kZW1vIiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJleHAiOjE5ODM4MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeoJeXxjNni43kdQwgnWNReilDMblYTn_I0')

There is a similar problem reported here, but the workaround appears to be React-specific and I don't know if it can be adapted by my situation. I'm very new to the whole stack.
Any insight appreciated.
